# Проблема с session_start() (Авторизация через ajax)

Tags: php, ajax

Пользователь входит на сайт Через ajax идет запрос на login.php

login.php:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['login']));
{
session_start();
$login = $_POST['login'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];
include ('config.php');
$log = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `db_users` WHERE username = '$login'"));

 $login_ms = $log['username'];
 $pass_ms = $log['password'];
 $steam_id = $log['steam_id'];
 $_SESSION['flag'] = $log['flags'];
if ($pass == '')
{
 echo "<div class='status-error'>Неправельный логин или пароль.</div>
<script>$('.status-error').slideDown('slow');
setTimeout(function() { 
$('.status-error').slideUp('slow'); 
}, 3000);
</script>"; 
}
else
{
    if ($login_ms == $login and $pass == $pass_ms)
    {
    $_SESSION['login'] = $login_ms;
    $_SESSION['steam_id'] =  $steam_id;
    echo "<div class='status-accept'>Добро пожаловать ".$login_ms.".</div>
    <script>$('.status-accept').slideDown('slow');
    setTimeout(function() { 
    $('.status-accept').slideUp('slow'); 
    }, 3000);
    setTimeout(function() { 
    window.location.replace('/');
    }, 1000);
    </script>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<div class='status-error'>Неправельный логин или пароль.</div>
    <script>$('.status-error').slideDown('slow');
    setTimeout(function() { 
    $('.status-error').slideUp('slow'); 
    }, 3000);
    </script>"; 
    }

 }
}


?>
```

Далее в head.php тоже запускаю session_start(); :

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="description" content="<?php echo $adm['sitename'].' - '.$adm['description'] ?>">
<meta name="keywords" content="">

<?php
session_start();
$adm = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `admin`'));
$users = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query('SELECT SUM(onl) as onl FROM `db_users`'));
$global = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query('SELECT SUM(db_users.kill) as kil,SUM(death)  as ded,SUM(animal)  as ani FROM `db_users`'));

?>
```

Index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<?php
include ('inc/config.php');
include ('inc/head.php');
?>
<body>
```

> NotePad++ UTF-8 БЕЗ BOOM не помогает. Если я перенесу **include
>   ('inc/head.php');** выше чем `<!DOCTYPE html>` тоже не помогает.

Comment: а если `echo 'hello';` убрать? ....... head включен в файл login?

Comment: Ну сам подумай, если у тебя head включен в  login, то что происходит? вот то и несу .........читаем http://cannot-modify-header-information.ru/    проникаемся

Comment: Обычыная процес авторизации если логин и пароль совпали кидаем в сессию.Я всё это несмогу сюда выложить куча кода.

Comment: Я, собственно, и не просил. Но вы, видимо, не понимаете о чем речь)) ... выложите как можете, а там уж можно и решить большой код или нет............... еще раз спрошу..... есть ли где-то место где вы пишите `include "head.php"`?

Comment: Да есть.Почти я ее использую везде )

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<?php
include ('inc/config.php');
include ('inc/head.php');
?>
<body>
 <?php
include ('inc/menu.php');
?>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
<div class="wrap">`...

Comment: А вот теперь проанализируйте.......`session_start` и `header` должны вызываться **до любого вывода**. Как вы думаете где стоит вывод информации `<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="ru">` до или после `head`? надеюсь намек понятен

Comment: Я пробовал на самый верх тащить не помогает

Comment: Походу придётся проста скрыть ошибки php, в таком коде искать такую маленькую проблему проста жесть сложно).В другой раз буду писать сайт с включенным режимом показа ошибок.)

Comment: `Если я перенесу include ('inc/head.php'); выше чем <!DOCTYPE html> тоже не помогает.`..............повторю **ЕЩЕ** раз... и прикреплю заново ссылку http://cannot-modify-header-information.ru/  и эту http://phpfaq.ru/newbie/headers ...... **session_start и header должны вызываться до любого вывода** ....... посмотрите...в файле `head.php` до `session_start()` что-то есть?

Comment: перенесите в самое начало  (!!!) файла `<?php
session_start(); ?>` и все заработает

Comment: @splash58, неа, потому что этот файл подключен в файл в котором до подключения выводится `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">`

Comment: @Grundy тьфу, точно - проглядел

Comment: тогда это проблема проектирования движка - весь вывод до последнего момента надо собирать в буфер, и только потом разгружать, чтоб у вас была возможность по ходу дела менять заголовки и другие настройки документа

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я поступил таким образом.Все `session_start();` убрал.Дале одну session_start(); добавил на config.php Далее уже делал include. **Да это самое важное чтобы `include('config.php');` должен быть всегда сверху всего)))**.Спасибо за помощь буду знать

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте сохранить файл в кодировке: UTF-8 без BOM.

Сделать это можете в программах Notepad2, Notepad++ и т.д.

Если не помогло, то прочтите [это](http://phpfaq.ru/newbie/headers)

Answer (score 0):

Эта ошибка говорит о том что у вас что-то выводится на экран до вызова функции `session_start()`. Если там ничего нет, возможно у вашего редактора кодировка `utf-8`, а должна быть `utf-8 без BOM` так как добавляются лишние символы вначале файла.

Comment: Я проверил только что все файлы "utf-8 без BOM"

Comment: Покажите код файла в котором возникает ошибка

Comment: Ошибка возникает где находится session_start то есть если я перенесу его на другой menu.php то показывает ошибку на неём.

Comment: Если я ёё уберу то текст hello не показывается то есть сессию не видит.

Comment: Я это прочел в вашем вопросе. Покажите пожалуйста код файла что бы я мог посмотреть что у вас до `session_start()`. Если ты покажешь код файла мне будет значительно проще тебе помочь :)

Comment: Залил специально для вас ).Сверху

Comment: Как я и говорил `session_start();` у вас после 
`<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="description" content="<?php echo $adm['sitename'].' - '.$adm['description'] ?>">
<meta name="keywords" content="">`
 а должен быть над.

Comment: Если вам помог ответ ставьте пожалуйста галочку, что бы другие могли быстро найти верный ответ.

Comment: Я поступил таким образом.Все `session_start();`  убрал.Дале одну `session_start();` добавил на config.php Далее уже делал include. Да это самое важное чтобы `include('config.php');` Должен быть всегда сверху всего))).Спасибо за помощь буду знать

Answer (score 0):

А Вы создайте новый файл без бом и скопируйте содержимое старого и переименуйте.
ну и соответственно вся цепочка подключаемых файлов должна быть без бом и ничего не должно выводиться до старта сессии